# Acessing string parameter data from a List of Type Class

Tags: c#, list, class, subclass, custom-data-type

I currently have a List of custom type

```
Eg: List<CustomDataType> myList = new List<CustomDataType>();
```

Its data type is a class. Each of these classes stored in the list contain subclasses that include additional overloaded parameters as well as the base class parameters.

```
Eg(general form): CustomDataType listItem = new Subclass(data1, data2, data3, overloadedData1, overloadedData2) etc...
myList.Add(listItem);
```

After the creation, I need to take in the data of each element from the List and save it as a string in a text file
For this I have a foreach loop set up

```
foreach (CustomDataType listNum in myList)
    {
       //Code to extract data goes here here



       //Should have all of the class data in a string to be ready for writing
       txtFile.WriteLine(theDataFromClass)


    }

txtFile.Close();
```

I also need all of the data inside the list element to be converted to string so it can be properly written down in the file.

If anything is unclear I'd be happy to give the source code, although for this occasion I wanted to rewrite it in a general format

PS there IS indeed data being assigned properly. My question is about being able to access that data.

I hope everything is clear!

Answer (score 1):

> I also need all of the data inside the list element to be converted to string so it can be properly written down in the file.

So you need to write a method which does exactly that. There are any number of ways of converting things to strings - you need to write the code to do it, quite possibly within `CustomDataType`. You could override `ToString` or create another virtual method, overridden in subclasses. Note that if you're expecting to be able to parse the result, you may need to think about escaping some elements of the data.

If you're *only* using the text file to serialize and deserialize the data, you might want to consider using XML serialization or JSON serialization instead of doing it manually.

(Small note: I think you mean that the various classes contain *fields* or perhaps *properties* - only a *method* or indexer declares a parameter.)

Comment: (Small note: I think you mean that the various classes contain *fields* or perhaps *properties* - only a *method* or indexer declares a parameter.)

They do indeed contain parameters. I create the main class with general parameters and the subclasses are linked to the base class(thus containing the original parameters+specific parameters) Here's an example

    `public MainClass(string data1, string data2, string data3)` 

A subclass would contain:

    `public SubClass(string data1, string data2, string data3, string customData1, string customData2) : base data1, data2, data3)`

Comment: @ad: Those are constructor parameters, but unless you've saved the values in fields then it's lost. The existence of parameters doesn't help you on its own. Parameters only represent information *for the duration of a call*. You're interested in the *state of the object*, and state is held in fields.

Comment: Ah, I see thanks for clearing that up. I have always referred to them as parameters regardless, but technicality proves otherwise :). All of the parameters ARE given values during the creation of each subclass. Something like this.

`string data1 = dataSource[0];`
`stringData2 = dataSource[1]` and so on. The data is definitely there, I'm just having trouble accessing it.

Comment: @a d: Well you haven't shown us what your code looks like, so it's impossible to give you any more help than I've already shown, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Most basic solution is to override ToString() in `CustomDataType` and produce some sort of formatted output that is useful to you:

```
public override string ToString()
{
  return string.Format(
    "{0}, {1}, {2}",
    this.data1,
    this.data2,
    this.data3);
}
```

In derived types, you also override ToString() to provide any additional output, plus call the base class to include those values:

```
public override string ToString()
{
  return string.Format(
    "{0}, {1}, {2}",
    base.ToString(),
    this.derivedData1,
    this.derivedData2);
}
```

Now, your output loop should work something like this:

```
foreach (CustomDataType listNum in myList)
{
    txtFile.WriteLine(listNum.ToString());
}
```